# Desktop manager error ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I just did an upgrade last night to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
It seems there is a problem and it would be great to fix it.
Also it seems this is preveniting Wallsh (desktop wallpaper changer) from working.

I keep getting the following error message:

Error:

```
Desktop manager is not active
```

Comment: This problem has been solved on this [link][1]


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129002/ubuntu-14-04-lts-desktop-manager

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been reported previously. The bug report is available [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/variety/+bug/1301651)

The link also mentions a few possible solutions. The one that worked for me uninstalling `pcmanfm` completely and reinstalling.